# Chrome's issue with Spring Security

Tags: spring, google-chrome, security

I have a simple web application with spring security. Everything is ok in My own pc with Ubuntu and chrome/firefox. In office same code works fines in Fedora 28 and firefox. But Chrome in office has some strange issue.

This is my http config in spring configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/edit" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/info" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="hasAnyRole('USER, ADMIN')"/>

        <form-login login-page="/auth"
            authentication-failure-url="/auth?auth_error=1"
            login-processing-url="/my-login"
            password-parameter="my-password"
            username-parameter="my-username"
            default-target-url="/" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>
```

I should send this request to http://127.0.0.1:8080/users/edit and be redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth and after I singed in I must go back /users/edit. In Fedora and Chrome I see it goes back to home instead of /users/edit. It seems the session gets expired because every time I have to login and same scenario happens.

This [link](https://github.com/mehdizj2000/simple-web-xml) is a sample code in github and the Chrome version in Fedora 28 is "Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)"